# Display specific record from for loop

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a `for` loop that displays set of data from age 22 to 60

```
$amount = 3150;
$age = 22;
$fv_21 = futureValue('.045', 1, 0, $amount) * -1;
echo $fv_21;
echo "<br>";

$fee_21 = round($fv_21 / 100 * 1.5, 2);
echo $fee_21;
echo "<br>";

$balance = $fv_21 - $fee_21;
echo $balance;
echo "<br><br><br>";
//exit;

for ($x = $age; $x <= 60; $x++) {
    //calculate super amount
    $amount = round($amount * 1.025, 2);
    echo "amount_$x = $amount<br>";

    //calculate FV
    $fv = round(futureValue('.045', 1, $amount, $balance) * -1,2);
    echo "FV of age $x is : " . $fv;
    echo "<br>";

    //calculate fee
    $fee = round(futureValue('.045', 1, $amount, $balance) * -1 / 100 * 1.5, 2);
    echo "Fee of age $x is: $fee";
    echo "<br>";
    //calculate balance
    $balance = $fv - $fee;
    echo "Balance of age $x is : ".round($balance,2);
    echo "<br><br><br>";
}
```

this is the output that i get

```
amount_22 = 3228.75
FV of age 22 is : 6617.03
Fee of age 22 is: 99.26
Balance of age 22 is : 6517.77


amount_23 = 3309.47
FV of age 23 is : 10120.54
Fee of age 23 is: 151.81
Balance of age 23 is : 9968.73


amount_24 = 3392.21
FV of age 24 is : 13809.53
Fee of age 24 is: 207.14
Balance of age 24 is : 13602.39
```

I would like to achieve displaying data of certain age only, for example if the user logs into the system and if his age is 23 then display data for age 23 only, how can i extract this data from the loop?

Important: The data for age 23 is dependent on data of age 22, data from age 24 is dependent on data from age 23 and so on.

I will really appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction.

**UPDATE:**
This is the `futureValue()` function I am using

```
function futureValue($rate, $nper, $pmt, $pv = 0, $type = 0)
{
    if ($nper < 0) {
        return PEAR::raiseError('Number of periods must be positive');
    }
    if ($type != FINANCE_PAY_END && $type != FINANCE_PAY_BEGIN) {
        return PEAR::raiseError('Payment type must be FINANCE_PAY_END or FINANCE_PAY_BEGIN');
    }

    if ($rate) {
        $fv = -$pv * pow(1 + $rate, $nper) - $pmt * (1 + $rate * $type) * (pow(1 + $rate, $nper) - 1) / $rate;
    } else {
        $fv = -$pv - $pmt * $nper;
    }
    return $fv;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the age of user who logins into a session variable like this

```
session_start()
$_SESSION['age']="23";// some value here
```

And inside for loop add if block like this

```
for ($x = $age; $x <= 60; $x++) {
    $amount = round($amount * 1.025, 2);
    $fv = round(futureValue('.045', 1, $amount, $balance) * -1,2);
    $fee = round(futureValue('.045', 1, $amount, $balance) * -1 / 100 * 1.5, 2);
    $balance = $fv - $fee;

    if($age == $_SESSION['age']) {  <- new condition added

    echo "amount_$x = $amount<br>";
    echo "FV of age $x is : " . $fv;
    echo "<br>";

    echo "Fee of age $x is: $fee";
    echo "<br>";

    echo "Balance of age $x is : ".round($balance,2);
    echo "<br><br><br>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
for ($x = $age; $x <= 60; $x++) {

    //calculate super amount
    $amount = round($amount * 1.025, 2);

    //calculate FV
    $fv = round(futureValue('.045', 1, $amount, $balance) * -1,2);

    //calculate fee
    $fee = round(futureValue('.045', 1, $amount, $balance) * -1 / 100 * 1.5, 2);

    //calculate balance
    $balance = $fv - $fee;

    if($x == $loggedInUserId) {
        echo "amount_$x = $amount<br>";
        echo "FV of age $x is : " . $fv;
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Fee of age $x is: $fee";
        echo "<br>";
        echo "Balance of age $x is : ".round($balance,2);
        echo "<br><br><br>";
    }

}
```